# Datatables stateSave keeps filters but not pagination

Tags: datatables, pagination

I am using Datatables to present data to my customers and I have a number of pages to display.

I'm using the stateSave option to save search filter etc.. but for some reason, the current page is not saved and uppon reload, the page is always back to #1.

I've tried to set bStateSave as well... but did not work and now I'm a bit lost.

Here is my table init code :

```
var table = $('#products').DataTable({
            "bStateSave": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]],
            "order": [[ 3,"asc"]],
            "responsive": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "paging": true,
            "language": {
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search products",
            },
            initComplete: function () {
                $('#products').show();
            }

    });
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to fix the problem ?

Thanks a lot for your help